# MVC 5 Routing with dynamic culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, culture

I have this route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{text}",
            defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, text = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { culture = supportedCulture }
        );
```

In global.asax I've added a cookie with the culture:

```
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("_culture", CultureName));
```

I would like to retrieve the default culture from that cookie.

Any ideas would be appreciated.